Problem with MSMQ and adding Public Queue
Hi I have a problem with adding Public Queue on Windows Server 2019. First when I install MSMQ and I go to Computer Management I do not see the Public Queue, but when I go to the Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters and change the Workgroup from 1 to 0, then I see the Public Queue but when I try to add I get this error:

Keep in mind that this windows server machine is on domain of the company, and here is how I install MSMQ:

What is the solution to this problem?
I tried to Add Public Queue for AAA services, I was expecting when I installed MSMQ that I will see Public Queue and I can automatically add objects to it.
